# Можно ли поставить Visual Studio 2017 оффлайн?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Привет есть офлайн установщик
хочу поставить C# только
можно без интернета это сделать?

или все равно интернет просит?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt706497.aspx

Comment: Можете скачать оффлайн кэш откуда-то с торрента, например, отсюда: [VS 2017 Community offline cache](http://nnm-club.me/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1222602)

Answer (score 0):

если C# есть в сборке то можно. Если нет - то нет. У меня ставилось с оф диска нормально.

Comment: C# в сборке есть... при установке не просит выхода в интернет? когда устанавливать буду...

Comment: @user301901 2013 студию нормально ставил без интернета.

Answer (score 0):

Можно с помощью Web-установщика создать локальное зеркало и устанавливать его без интернета. [Подробности есть тут](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/visual-studio-2017-installation-using-offline-installer/)